# Time interval in influxdb not matching with the interval set in telegraf config

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

In the telegraf agent I have set the interval as 5s. But in influxdb sometimes I am seeing long intervals between timestamps, for example 40s to 50s. Because of this, the graph in grafana showing blank spots which is giving a wrong impression to user.

Below are the timestamps. Please notice the third row where the time difference is 49 seconds. So, between 11:52:08 AM and 11:52:57 AM grafana will plot a blank spot, that's the problem. But, I monitored CPU metrics using Performance Monitor, counters like "Privileged Time" and "User Time" do have data during that blank period.

Any idea, what am I doing wrong?

```
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:52:02 AM .... +2s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:52:08 AM .... +6s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:52:57 AM .... +49s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:01 AM .... +4s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:05 AM .... +4s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:22 AM .... +17s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:26 AM .... +4s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:51 AM .... +25s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:53:55 AM .... +4s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:54:06 AM .... +11s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:54:12 AM .... +6s
Wednesday, October 2, 2019 04:54:16 AM .... +4s
```

[image]

```
[global_tags]
  domain = "$USERDOMAIN"
  username = "$USERNAME"
  hostname = "$COMPUTERNAME"


[agent]
  interval = "5s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_buffer_limit = 2000
  flush_buffer_when_full = true
  collection_jitter = "3s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "3s"
  precision = "s"
  debug = false
  quiet = true
  hostname = "$COMPUTERNAME"
  # logfile = "C:\\Program Files\\Monitor.log"

[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://primary.xxxxx.com:8686", "http://secondary.xxxxx.com:8686"]
  database = "xxxx"
  timeout = "5s"
  user_agent = "monitor"

[[inputs.win_perf_counters]]
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "Processor"
    Instances = ["*"]
    Counters = ["% Idle Time", "% Interrupt Time", "% Privileged Time", "% User Time", "% Processor Time", "% DPC Time",]
    Measurement = "win_cpu"
    IncludeTotal=true
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "LogicalDisk"
    Instances = ["*"]
    Counters = [ "% Idle Time", "% Disk Time", "% Disk Read Time", "% Disk Write Time", "Current Disk Queue Length", "% Free Space", "Free Megabytes",]
    Measurement = "win_disk"
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "PhysicalDisk"
    Instances = ["*"]
    Counters = [ "Disk Read Bytes/sec", "Disk Write Bytes/sec", "Disk Reads/sec", "Disk Writes/sec", "% Disk Time", "% Disk Read Time", "% Disk Write Time",]
    Measurement = "win_diskio"
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "Network Interface"
    Instances = ["*"]
    Counters = [ "Bytes Received/sec", "Bytes Sent/sec", "Packets Received/sec", "Packets Sent/sec", "Packets Received Errors", "Packets Outbound Errors",]
    Measurement = "win_net"
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "System"
    Counters = [ "Context Switches/sec", "System Calls/sec", "System Up Time",]
    Instances = ["------"]
    Measurement = "win_system"
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "Memory"
    Counters = [ "Available Bytes", "Pages/sec",]
     Instances = ["------"]
    Measurement = "win_mem"
  [[inputs.win_perf_counters.object]]
    ObjectName = "Paging File"
    Counters = [ "% Usage",]
    Instances = ["_Total"]
    Measurement = "win_swap"

  [[inputs.ping]]
    urls = ["ping.xxxx.com"]
    count = 1
```

Telegraf 1.3.6
Windows 10 (64 bit)

Comment: You have a flush_interval > interval. Furthermore, it might take longer to collect the metrics than 5s. Furthermore, your metric buffer limit is VERY low - might well be that a lot of the metrics are simply thrown away - they are flushed when full, but only after a successful flush the buffer is reset. And 5s for the metrics you are gathering is an overkill. From what I can see, 1m would be more than sufficient in any real world scenario. In general, you should understand _all_ config options - not just tweak one and hope for the best. This is polite for: rt*m ;)

Comment: I have been able to figure it out. The metrics are actually getting splitted among the 2 InfluxDB instances as I have set 2 URLs in the `[[outputs.influxdb]]` section. Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I will consider increasing the `metric_buffer_limit` to avoid any possible data loss.

Comment: Dang, missed that! If you want to send the data to two instances, you can have a look at [influxdb-relay](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-relay). I can attest it is production-ready.